# Linking another Cmake project's includes

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have an executable project and a library project. The library project is compiled with boost and other libraries. The executable project requires library project to be linked.

So far I've linked the library project in the executable project, however, there is a still a problem that the header files of library project includes boost. When I try to compile the executable project, it fails as boost is not linked in the executable project.

I want to link and include all the boost and external libraries/directories from the library project and also include all the compiler settings done in library project's CMakeLists.txt. Is there way that CMake can do this automatically?

Additional Information: I already have FindLibraryProject CMake find module.

Comment: For this I create a Use file that for my library has the finders for any dependent library.

Comment: #drescherjm I didn't get it. Library project is linked but the other libraries which are linked in library project is not linked to the executable project

Comment: I thought in your executable project you were using a find_package to find a library project (lets call it MyLib) that you have created in some other location. For that you can have a MyLibConfig.cmake that can specify a use file. In that MyLibConfig.cmake you can set a variable containing the location of a use script that can be executed after the package is found using the standard include ( ${MyLibConfig_USE_FILE} ).